# I need help restructuring some Tikz code

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I am trying to render the commutative diagram below in such a way that the arrows u and v are reversed, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
$ \begin{tikzcd}
\Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_{T}) \arrow[ddr, bend right, "v"] \arrow[drr, bend left, "u"] && \\
& A \otimes_{R} B \arrow[ul, dotted, "{ \exists \; ! \; \theta}"] & B \arrow[l, "q"] \\
& A \arrow[u, "p"] & R \arrow[l, "t"] \arrow[u, "r"] 
\end{tikzcd} $
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please, extend your code to complete small document (cale3d minimal working example: *mwe*) beginning with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

[image]

you need to move beginnings of those arrow to their destination and direct them to opposite directions  ...

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_{T})
    &   &   \\
    & A \otimes_{R} B \arrow[ul, dotted, "{ \exists \; ! \; \theta}"] % <--
        & B \arrow[l, "q"] \arrow[ull, bend right, "u" ']   \\
    & A \arrow[u, "p"] \arrow[uul, bend left, "v"]
        & R \arrow[l, "t"] \arrow[u, "r"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```